# Will this result in object slicing?

Tags: c++, object-slicing

Say I have an array of pointers to an abstract class:

```
Piece *pieces[2]; // where piece is an abstract class
```

And I have two classes that extend `Piece` called `King` and `Queen`.  I assign a `King` to a spot in `pieces` and `Queen` to another spot:

```
pieces[0] = new King();
pieces[1] = new Queen();
```

If I haven't overloaded the assignment operator, does slicing occur?  Or does `pieces[0]` is an instance of `King` and `pieces[1]` is an instance of `Queen`?  What is going on in that array (if this was C++)?

EDIT: See a full example of the code in question [here](http://ideone.com/16BEF).

Comment: I can pretend there are no compiler errors, but that doesn't mean I can pretend I know what the resulting code does.  Please fix your code to be actual C++.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ok, I changed it to what I think best gives an example of what my question is.  I didn't want to portray the wrong question through my code, so originally that's why I tried to make the code just portray the idea without worrying about syntax.

Comment: You had it half right before.  You fixed one thing(removing the dereference (`*`)), but broke another(replacing `new` with `&`).  Your code now compiles, but what you're doing is undefined behavior(even if it appears to work).  You're creating a temporary object, then storing its address.  Don't do that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Just to clarify my understanding of what's going on, does this mean once it's out of scope my pointer is pointing to nothing?

Comment: Something like that.  And it goes out of scope at the semi-colon.  What you want is this: `pieces[0] = new King; pieces[1] = new Queen;`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Wow, I didn't know it went out of scope so fast! I'll make sure I avoid doing that in the future and I've change example code to reflect what you suggested. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Also remember that since you are using `new`, you need an accompanying `delete`, otherwise you have memory leaks.  So when you are done with your objects, you need to do this: `delete pieces[0]; delete pieces[1];`  If you used a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_Smart_Pointers), you could avoid that tedium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't actually compile: you can't assign a `King *` (the type of the expression `new King`) to a `Piece` (the type of the expression `*pieces[0]`).

To answer your implied question, though:

```
Piece *piece = new King(); // fine, no slicing, just assigning a pointer
*piece = Queen();          // oops, slicing - assigning a Queen to a Piece
```

In the array in your question, assuming you'd written `pieces[0] = new King;`, etc., you'd just be storing two `Piece` pointers, one of which points to a `King` and one of which points to a `Queen`.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Sorry about the code not compiling; I am a student and I was just wondering about the concept but I'm still trying to completely understand pointer arrays. I will change the code to make it compile, when I get home where I can test and compile the code, so that others looking at this question in the future wont be confuse.

Comment: @AustinMoore: If you have an internet connection, you can always test your code (as long as you stick to the standard library): http://ideone.com/

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for that link actually :) I use http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout for compiling things online, but it doesn't link or run...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you, I did not know about that!  I will fix it now then :)

Answer (score 1):

No slicing will occur. You're doing pointer assignment, not object assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes slicing will occur.

Slicing will always occur whenever you are trying to put derived class object to any of its base class. This slicing will become visible if your derived class has added some functionality that your base class do not provide.

Remember, this is the case when you are not following OOP principals. Principal says,

```
"When you are deriving from any class you should not change the interface. 
The reason for inheritance is moving from generic to specific type, and not
 providing new functionality."
```

And, if you follow this principal then slicing behaviour can be defined as,

```
“Moving from specific behaviour to more general behaviour”.
```

Slicing through pointer objects are temporary and you can cast the pointer back to derived class to get the original behaviour. Slicing through the object is permanent.

```
NOTE:- Slicing always does not happen in case of private inheritance. 
If you try to do so it will result in compilation error.
(For more information on private inheritance:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075517/object-slicing-in-private-inheritance/19083420?noredirect=1#19083420)
```