# Object slicing in private inheritance

Tags: c++, object-slicing, private-inheritance

Why object slicing does not takes place in private inheritance?  Static_cast gives error in such cases?
I understand that the private inheritance does not hold “is - a” relationship between its inheritance classes. Does this has something to do with slicing since derived is not of type base so compiler is forcing not to do implicit conversion?

Comment: Show some code. Converting an object of a derived type to an object of a base type slices the object. That's what slicing means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to slice a derived class to its private base class. Just consider for a moment what 'private' means. It means that the outside world should not care about it. Allowing slicing (casting) to a private base means the outside world would care.

If you really want this behavior (I'd love to hear your reasons), you can hack around it:

```
class Base { };
struct Derived : private Base 
{
    Base asBase() { return static_cast<Base>(*this); }
};
```

This way, the cast happens inside Derived, where Base is accessible. The error you got from static_cast is because it was used outside of the scope of Derived, where Base is not accessible.

Comment: I think I understood what you are trying to say...One more thing, Thanks for showing the way to get the base pointer, but is it really needed?

Comment: I'm not showing how to get the Base _pointer_. The 'asBase' function slices the Derived object to a Base (note that the return value of asBase is 'Base', not 'Base*' or 'Base&', which both would not slice the object). The whole point is that the slicing cannot be done from outside the scope of Derived, because Base is a private base. This is why you 'need' the slicing to happen inside the scope of Derived. Hope this clarifies things.